# Insertar un numero consecutivo en una campo ordenado por otro campo en sql 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tardes colega ten la siguiente caso a ver si me ayudan a resolver resulta que estoy trabajando en `sql  server 2012`.

Quiero que inserte un número consecutivo  en un campo `x` de acuerdo a un orden determinado ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código

```
DECLARE @id AS INT    
SELECT  @id =ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.COD_ART) , a.COD_ART FROM ARTFISIC AS a GROUP BY A.COD_ART ORDER BY a.COD_ART asc

UPDATE ARTFISIC
SET
MARCA_MARB='X',
    MARBETE=@id,
    CONTEO01='0',
     CONTEO02='0',
      CONTEO03='0',
      CONTEOCERO='0',
      DIFERENCIA='0',
      EXIST_CONT='0',
      ENT_RETRO='0',
      SAL_RETRO='0',
    EXIST_FISI='0',
    FIS_VS_TEO='0'
```

Me marca el siguiente error:

> Una instrucción SELECT que asigna un valor a una variable no debe
>   combinarse con operaciones de recuperación de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero de su acostumbrada ayuda de antemano le agradezco

Dios le bendiga

Comment: Jose por favor comparte algo de datos para entender un poco mejor tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: ¿qué liga el campo A o el consecutivo con el campo B? Por favor lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: El error es claro, para que agregas al select a.COD_ART si estas asignando un row_number a @id?

Comment: pero si no me agrega el consecutivo en el campo marbete como puedes ver en la segundo imagen

Comment: no puedes hacer que COD_ART sea un consecutivo, fijate que en el id 2633 tienes un numero diferente a los que le siguen, Trata de hacer una tabla temporal y haz un select de los que son consecutivos y los que no lo son

Comment: Veamoslo de otra forma.. para que quere numerar consecutivamente los registros? tal vez el problema tenga otra solucion.

Comment: es que el consecutivo es numero de marbete que va tener ese articulo a la hora de hacer el inventario

Comment: @gbianchi no entiendo como asi ejemplo porfavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que, tenes que crear una tabla temporal con los datos ordenados primero, para poder numerarlos.

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.COD_ART ASC) as Numero, a.COD_ART
into #TablaTemporal
FROM ARTFISIC AS a
```

Esta tabla, te va a poner un numero delante de cada articulo

Luego, con esta tabla, podemos hacer un update de la otra tabla, igualando el campo Marbete a Numero

```
UPDATE ARTFISIC set a.Marbete = b.numero
From ARTFISIC as a inner join 
#TablaTemporal as b on a.COD_ART = b.COD_ART
```

Recuerda dropear la tabla temporal una vez que hayas terminado (aunque la misma deberia desaparecer una vez que te desconectes).